# PHP T-variable in HTML form

Tags: php, html, forms

The following code is throwing a T-variable exception in line 10

```
 //Two Email Lines
$email_to = "contact@website.com";
$email_subject = "AUTO: WEB BETA INVITE REQUEST";

//Set equal to email form textbox
$email_form = $_POST["email_text"];



$email_message = "Email: "$email_form"";

//Create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_form."\r\n".
@mail($email_to, $email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
```

When I change the = "Email: "$email_form""; to single quotes around the variables $email_form, it runs and throws no exception. However, it sends an email that says "Email: ''", as in, it reads the $email_form variable as blank, which it was not.

The HTML code for the form is below.

```
<form method="post" action="Email_Form_Script.php" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="window.open('FormPopUp.html','popup','width=500,height=500,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');" >
<div><input type="text" class="text" name="email_text" id="emailForm" value="Enter your e-mail address" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter your e-mail address') { this.value = '' }" onblur="if(this.value=='') { this.value = 'Enter your e-mail address' }" /><input type="hidden" value="" name="email2"/><input type="hidden" name="loc" value="en_US"/><input type="submit" class="submit" value="" 
            /></div></form>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: $email_message = "Email: $email_form";

Comment: Why would you ever suppress errors on `mail()`?  I don't believe it can even throw an exception!  Don't suppress problems, catch and handle appropriately, or fix them.

Comment: also: $headers = 'From: '.$email_form."\r\n"; overall, there are some formatting issues / bad practices

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments. This is my first time really working with PHP so I am still learning. I am trying to get the web form to deliver the textbox input to an e-mail address. The form delivers an email, however, all it contains is "Email:   ", even though input was inserted into the textbox. There seems to be a problem with the PHP script not picking up the input from the textbox. I am a bit stumped as to what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
$email_message = "Email: "$email_form"";
```

to:

```
$email_message = "Email: " . $email_form . "";
```

You forgot to concatenate.

Comment: I agree, but that does not seem to be the problem. It is still arriving in my e-mail as the following text:  "Email:    " (So does not display textbox input).

Comment: It sounds like `$_POST["email_text"];` is empty. As @Brad said in the comments above, remove the `@` from `mail()` and see what errors you get. Also, you have `$email_form` in your headers, why?

Comment: Deleted the entire header section, it really wasn't needed. Removed @ from mail(). Email sent, but textbox variable still empty. Still not showing input.

Answer (score 1):

Change

`$email_message = "Email: "$email_form"";`

to

`$email_message = "Email: " . $email_form . "";`

Also it looks like you're missing a semicolon:

```
//Create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_form."\r\n". <---
```